# Specific formatting while exporting some data output into a file

Tags: functions, export, mathematical-optimization, files-and-directories

I used the following code

```
pUlimit = 5; pStep = 1; pStart = 1;
qUlimit = .005; qStep = .0005; qStart = .001;
p = Table[i, {i, pStart, pUlimit, pStep}];
q = Table[j, {j, qStart, qUlimit, qStep}];
dimp = Dimensions[p][[1]];
dimq = Dimensions[q][[1]];
```

Output in 'data3.dat' looks like

[image]

But when I use following code

```
data3 = Table[{p[[i]], q[[j]]}, {i, 1, dimp},{j,1,dimq}]
Export["data3.dat", data3];
```

Output in 'data3.dat' looks like this

[image]

But I want output like this in data3 file.,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
data3 = Flatten[Table[{p[[i]], q[[j]]}, {i, 1, dimp}, {j, 1, dimq}], 1]
Export["data3.dat", data3, "Table"];
```